# pandas add day to date and the number of day based on another column

Tags: python, pandas

In python, my dataframe like:

```
date1 num
2017-03-02 8
2017-04-15 4
2017-06-30 1
```

I want the result dataframe(add date2 columns) like this:

```
date1 num date2
2017-03-02 8 2017-03-10
2017-04-15 4 2017-04-19
2017-06-30 1 2017-07-01
```

I know :`df.date1 +pd.offsets.Day(x)`, but `x` is not allowed to be Series. And I know `apply()` function may could resolve this problem,
but the lines of my dataframe is over one billion.

So what to do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can add `timedeltas` created by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```
df['date2'] = df['date1'] + pd.to_timedelta(df['num'], unit='d')
print (df)
       date1  num      date2
0 2017-03-02    8 2017-03-10
1 2017-04-15    4 2017-04-19
2 2017-06-30    1 2017-07-01
```

If want add `month`s use [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with `axis=1` for proceses by rows and [dateoffset](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects):

```
df['date3'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['date1'] + pd.offsets.DateOffset(months=x['num']), 1)
print (df)
       date1  num      date3
0 2017-03-02    8 2017-11-02
1 2017-04-15    4 2017-08-15
2 2017-06-30    1 2017-07-30
```

Comment: Yeah, that's works for me, and if add one month should fill in 'M'? I watched the source code, but no month type in the map.

Comment: I think `apply` is nice, if not exist vectorized alternative. Good luck and thank you for accepting!